# Find the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD$ in the diagram

Tags: geometry

[image]

It is given that $BD=113$, $BC=112$, $\angle BCD=90˚$ and $AO:OC=2:1$. I'm supposed to find the area of ABCD.

I got up to $DC=15$, but I seriously have no idea what to do next. Can someone give me a hint? I don't even know the purpose of knowing $AO:OC=2:1$.

Comment: $AO:OC$ is the same as the ratio of the altitudes of triangles $ABD$ and $CBD$ on common base $BD$. Hence the area of $ABD$ is twice the area of $CBD$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Why would $AO:OC$ be the ratio of the altitudes if we do not know whether $AO$ and $OC$ are the heights of the triangles?

Comment: Just draw the altitudes and find two similar triangles.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Altitudes for triangle $ADB$ from $A$ and for triangle $CBD$ from $C$...? I still don't really get it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$DC^2=113^2-112^2$$
$$DC=15$$
Now $$AO:OC=1$$
Let area of DOC be x and area of COB=y

Area of AOD=2x (Base division theorem)

Area of AOB=2y (Base Division Theorem)

Area of quadrilateral ABCD= Area of AOD+ Area of BOC+ Area of AOB+ Area of DOC

Area of quadrilateral ABCD=3(x+y)

Area of quadrilateral ABCD = 3(Area of BDC)
$$=\frac{3(112)(15)}{2}=2520$$
If you find it useful upvote the answer.